# How to solve exception occurred during CURSOR retrieval from Callable Statement in Java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

I have return Db2 procedure which is returning cursor for one of table.

This procedure is called from my java code and truing to retrieve cursor as a result set and having flowing SQLexception exception log,

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jo: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][4.7.85] 
Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:666)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
```

I searched solution for this exception and found this solution on ibm website  [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21647500) which suggest to change log configuration,

> Increase the log file size and the number of primary and secondary log
>   files. The num_log_span value can also be adjusted.

Here is procedure example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC(c_dump OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
  open c_dump FOR
    select feild1,feild1,.... from RSPNSE_TABLE;
END;
```

Java Code is given below,

```
public void callStoredProc(){

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String proc = "{call ABC(?)}";

        try {
            dbConnection = connection;
            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(proc);

            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, DB2Types.CURSOR);


            // execute getDBUSERCursor store procedure
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();

            // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
            rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } 

    }
```

Now in this java code is breaking at this line `callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(proc);`

**Note:** Despite exception log contains *"Connection is closed"* text I want to mention that I had successfully established the connection with database normal retrieval using JDBC does not have problem.

Comment: The driver says connection is closed, you say it is not; who to believe? May be you want to call `isClosed()` or `isValid()` on the connection just before `prepareCall()`?

Comment: Can you provide products used and version numbers? Server OS, DB2 and JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

The prepare call failing indicates you don't have an open connection.  You'll have to dig into the SQLException and determine exactly why.